# How hot future will get depends on what humans do or how humans do to stop climate change? How or what?

Tags: word-choice

Should I use **what** instead of **how** in the following sentence and why ?

How hot future will get depends on **what** humans do to stop climate change. Governments appeal to people to reduce greenhouse gases ...

I think it should be **what** not how, but I can't explain the exact reason. I just feel it sounds more natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on **what** [actions] people do. **How** would introduce a description of the *way* an action was done.

Comment: My English teacher told me that if the sentence is " ... depends on how humans do it to ...", i.e. with an "it", then use **how** here would be correct, without "it" **what** sounds more natural. Does that make sense ?

Comment: If you use _how humans do it_, you need to have first said what _it_ refers to.